# Swift get value from Dictionary

Tags: swift

please help me to get values from response

```
{
  "BU": {
    "name": "Bulawayo",
    "names": "Bulawayo"
  },
  "HA": {
    "name": "Harare",
    "names": "Harare"
  }
}
```

i want value of key name. my code is below

```
let response = responseObject as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
let stateNames = response.values as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
```

**getting this issue:**

```
cannot cast from lazyMapCollection<Dictionary<String,Anyobject>,String> in swift
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get the value of "BU" as`response.valueForKey("BU").valueForKey("name")` it will give you the value "Bulawayo".

Comment: @Bhuatik the response is from server so i cannot specify the key name

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Please check my answer.

Comment: @Tripthi Haridas you can try respose.result.value.valueForKey("BU").valueForKey("name") if you are using Alamofire.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all the name then try like this

```
var name = [String]()
let keyArray = responseDic.allKeys as! [String]
for key in keyArray {
    let nameDic = responseDic.valueForKey(key) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    name.append(nameDic.valueForKey("name") as! String)
}
```

Comment: cast from lazyMapcollection<<Dictionary,AnyObject>,String> to unrelated type String

Comment: have you created array of string like i have created for `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to access the values:

```
if let responseBU = response["BU"] {
   let name = responseBU["name"]
   let names = responseBU["names"] 
}
```

Comment: name BU cannot be used. values are different from server

Comment: Do you mean to say the keys are dynamic in nature? You should be using your server send keys instead of "BU"  @ThripthiHaridas

Comment: If you really do not know what the keys are ,then you can get all keys like this: let allKeys = Array(response.keys). @ThripthiHaridas